# Can one validation rule prevent record creation and editing for particular picklist values

Tags: validation-rule

Trying to prevent users from being able to create the record if the field Configuration_Request_Type__c is "Feature" or "Enhancement", but also not edit the same field once record is created by another. Only a list of users can create or edit the field with the values of "Feature" or "Enhancements".

Configuration_Request_Type__c has 3 values:

- Feature
- Enhancements
- Fix

This VR won't allow them to create with those values, BUT how can I stop them from editing the same field?

```
AND(
    (ISNEW()),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Configuration_Request_Type__c,'Feature'),
        ISPICKVAL(Configuration_Request_Type__c,'Enhancement')
    ),
    OR(
        $User.Id !="005d0000002mKHp", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000000Twif",
        $User.Id !="005d0000000TvOu", 
        $User.Id !="0050V000007Mlad", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000000TuyJ", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000000TvrH", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000001VFkj", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000001Wyup", 
        $User.Id !="0050V0000075L2C", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000002mIBQ", 
        $User.Id !="005d0000005n0pm", 
        $User.Id !="0050V000006kNzs", 
        $User.Id !="0050V000006kNt7", 
        $User.Id != "005d0000005I9dx", 
        $User.Id != "005d00000040uDS", 
        $User.Id != "0053o000008r0a8", 
        $User.Id != "0053o000009lIz3", 
        $User.Id != "0053o00000AaU4u" 
    )
)
```

Comment: Quick tips for validation rules in general: 1 - When you're checking a single field against multiple values, you need to use `AND()` when comparing inequality (and `OR()` when comparing equality). 2 - Hard-coding Ids is generally a bad idea. This would be better as a custom permission.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I stop them from editing the same field?

By creating another validation rule.

Validation rules can only emit a single error message, so some good rules of thumb to determine if you need a separate validation rule are:

- Do you need to emit a different error message in your additional scenario?
- Should the error appear on a different field (or on a specific field instead of on the overall record)?

Answering "yes" to either means you should probably have a separate validation rule.

Beyond that, the thing you're looking for is the `ISCHANGED()` function (e.g. `ISCHANGED(Configuration_Request_Type__c)`). A plain language version of the validation formula might be

> Prevent the record from saving when: Request Type has changed, and the current user doesn't have the permission set that allows them to change the request type.